# NodeJS Post Request - Numbers in params returning NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, parseint

I'm newish to NodeJS. Trying to make a POST request, but all the integers in the params are being passed as NaN. On the second line below, you 
 can see in the request that actual numbers are assigned to the params, but then the first line where the post request is happening, all the numbers are NaN. What am I missing here?

```
2018-08-06T20:44:24.391354+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): INSERT INTO "public"."meetings" ("id","requestor_id","requestee_id","lang_one_id","lang_two_id","meeting_time","accepted","status","requestor_score","requestee_score") VALUES (DEFAULT,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'2018-08-06 20:44:24.000 +00:00',false,'Active',0,0) RETURNING *;
2018-08-06T20:44:24.401308+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/meetings/createMeeting?requestor_id=32&requestee_id=1&meeting_time=2018-08-16%2013:00:00&location=NYC&location_address=NYC&lang_one_id=1&lang_two_id=2 500 59.324 ms - 1272
```

Controller:

```
meetings.createMeeting = (req, res) => {
  const { requestor_id, requestee_id, meeting_time, accepted, location, location_address, status, lang_one_id, lang_two_id } = req.body;
  let data = {
    requestor_id: parseInt(requestor_id),
    requestee_id: parseInt(requestee_id),
    meeting_time: Date(meeting_time),
    accepted: false,
    location,
    location_address,
    status: "Active",
    lang_one_id: parseInt(lang_one_id),
    lang_two_id: parseInt(lang_two_id),
    requestor_score: parseInt(0),
    requestee_score: parseInt(0),
    created_at: Date.now(),
    updated_at: Date.now()
  };
  models.Meetings.create(data)
    .then(response => {
      res.status(200).json({ status: 200, message: response });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({ status: 500, err: error });
    });
};
```

When I change to `req.params` none of the data is present:

```
2018-08-06T21:11:21.830182+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): INSERT INTO "public"."meetings" ("id","requestor_id","requestee_id","lang_one_id","lang_two_id","meeting_time","accepted","status","requestor_score","requestee_score") VALUES (DEFAULT,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'2018-08-06 21:11:21.000 +00:00',false,'Active',0,0) RETURNING *;
2018-08-06T21:11:21.849573+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/meetings/createMeeting?requestor_id=32&requestee_id=1&meeting_time=2018-08-16%2013:00:00&location=NYC&location_address=NYC&lang_one_id=1&lang_two_id=2 500 51.120 ms - 1272
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like:

```
  const { requestor_id, requestee_id, meeting_time, accepted, location, location_address, status, lang_one_id, lang_two_id } = req.body;
```

Should be:

```
  const { requestor_id, requestee_id, meeting_time, accepted, location, location_address, status, lang_one_id, lang_two_id } = req.params;
```

Or wherever the query parameters are from your request object. Given that you are invoking your post request with query params rather than a payload in the request body.

Comment: Yep, that looks exactly right. The values that are coming through are all the defaults, or date which is just generating the current datetime because it's getting `null` (e.g. `Date(null) => 
"Mon Aug 06 2018 13:56:39 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is an API - so I'll be sending the data by body, not params. But when I update to req.params, I get the same response. I'll post the logs above in the question.

Comment: Looking at this, I thought the issue was NaN, but as @supremebeing7 pointed out, actually none of the data is correct. What am I missing here :/

Comment: `POST /api/meetings/createMeeting?requestor_id=32&requestee_id=1&meeting_time=2018-08-16%2013:00:00&location=NYC&location_address=NYC&lang_one_id=1&lang_two_id=2`


This is just using the query params, if you want to use the body you will have to set the payload in whatever is responsible for the server call.

It might not be exactly req.params, I'd recommend looking at your server's documentation for how to access the request's query params, and changing it to whatever that is

Comment: Okay - I'll look more into it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'd suggest logging out req in your handler, maybe that will help you find out where the values are being set! What server are you using by the way?